# Is it possible to do word completion on `isearch` shell?

Tags: completion, isearch

I want to apply word completion on `isearch` shell. When I press tab `^I` shows up on the shell instead of completing the word and show up a window for suggestions.

[image]

=> Is it possible to complete a word on `isearch` shell?

Comment: An interesting point is what information should it use for providing completion?  It needs to guess somehow the strings you want to search.

Comment: I just want it to detect information on the opened file (ex: `Driver.py` on the example I gave.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question seems unclear. What is "isearch shell"?

You seem to be using `TAB` during Isearch and expecting completion against previous search strings (?).  If so, the key you want is `C-M-TAB` (not `TAB`), which is bound to `isearch-complete` in `isearch-mode-map`.

But you say "complete a word", not complete against a previous search pattern, so the question seems quite unclear.

If you are just looking for full-word searching, that's on `M-s w` while isearching.

Comment: I am not sure for the proper definition for it, I try to refer when I do a `isearch` the interaction shell that show up on the bottom of the `emacs`

Comment: That's the echo area (being used kind of as if it were the minibuffer). But what are you asking about it?

Comment: For example I have a `hello_world` and `hello` variables on my file. When I type `he` into `isearch` and press `tab` I want it to complete into `hello_world` and press tab again complete into `hello` (I think this is behavior of `auto-complete`). But on my case when I press tab `^I` shows up instead of doing a completion

Comment: AFAIK, Isearch does not have such completion.

Comment: @alper It's not integrated with isearch but you might want to look at hippie-expand.

Comment: I checked `hippie-expand` but couldn't use it under `isearch`

Comment: As I noted, Isearch does not have such completion. The completion of standard library `completion.el`, `dabbrev`, `hippie-expand`, etc. are not usable during Isearch (out of the box) as far as I know.